# bootstrap help-block to show only if form-group has-error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a comment form that is showing also the bootstrap help-block as:

```
<p class="help-block">required</p>
```

I want this `p` to be hidden except when the form is submitted and the field is validated as an error.

when the form is submitted with an error, the parent `<div class="form-group">...</div>` gets an additional `has-error` class. How could I show the `help-block` only if there is an error in the form submission? Btw I have no access to the HTML...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### CSS way

```
.help-block { display: none; }
.form-group.has-error .help-block { display: block; }
```

#### jQuery way

```
$('.help-block').hide();

$('#yourForm').submit(function(){
  $.each($(this).find('.form-group'), function(){
    // Long but clear version
    if ( $(this).hasClass('has-error') ) {
      $(this).find('.help-block').show();
    } else {
      $(this).find('.help-block').hide();
    }

    // Shortest version
    // $(this).find('.help-block')[ $(this).hasClass('has-error') ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
  });
});
```