# Bootstrap 3 Validation state, 'Error' showing by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple `bootstrap 3` styled form. I have a `span` with `help-block` which I understand would be displayed if the parent `div` with class `form-group` also has `has-error` defined, however, the error help text is showing by default.

I found this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976143/bootstrap-help-block-to-show-only-if-form-group-has-error), however, I thought `Bootstrap` would take care of this hiding/unhiding logic. Is that an incorrect assumption? Am I supposed to take care of show-hide?

```
<form id="the-form" action="/abc" method="post">                                  

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
  <input id="title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" type="text" value="">    
  <span class="help-block">Title is not valid.</span>                   
 </div>

 <button id="create-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, the `error` text is shown by default:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When you add the class `has-error` to the `form-group` div.. Bootstrap is only applying the CSS error on elements inside of the from-group.

If you want to show the error msg only on errors. You have to show or hide it by JavaScript.. There are severals way to do it.. One It would be: Hide the err msg by default, you can do it with bootstrap class hidden

```
<span class="help-block hidden">Title is not valid.</span>
```

So when you are adding the class has-error to the form you should remove the class hidden from the help-block.. Then you need to add that class hidden again when the form is correct.. all of this with JS. That will work.